# Should we take Tridion Docs questions here?

Tags: discussion

With the recent announcement by SDL that Tridion Sites and Tridion Docs are merging to become [Tridion DX](https://www.sdl.com/software-and-services/tridion-dx/), and the fact that some software components (especially delivery) share the code base and design... would it make sense to start accepting/encouraging Tridion Docs questions on this stack exchange site?

In my opinion, we should - there is a very small partner network for Tridion Docs, and I believe the Tridion Sites partners will benefit from the added knowledge and business opportunities - having a safe space like this one to ask questions would be beneficial - and we don't even have to rename it!

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

It makes sense. I'd say we should welcome these questions. Considering that the two will be sold as part of the same product, from our point of view it's almost as though the product just got some new functionality.

In any case, as the integration between the two gets tighter, (or at least, the amount of common elements increases) the likelihood of questions that cross both areas will increase.

Comment: SDL Tridion Sites and SDL Tridion Docs would first be part of the same SDL Tridion DX _suite_, though they'll likely remain separate products for the foreseeable future.

Answer (score 3):

I agree Nuno. Having larger community can really boost up this stack. Besides this, having new users can be beneficial to both Tridion Sites and Tridion Docs (someone might dive in both if not previously).

Comment: We're definitely starting to seeing partners (like Content Bloom), implementers, analysts, and prospects take a keen interest in the combined offering.